# R - Convert a range of years into decade dummies

Tags: r

Assume I have a dataset containing the following two variables:

```
start.year <- c(1957, 1973, 1943, 1991, 2001, 1967)
end.year <- c(1980, 1998, 1965, 2011, 2006, 1984)
db <- data.frame(start.year, end.year)
```

with start.year and end.year indicating, respectively, the beginning and the end of an observation period. 
I'd like to create a set of dichotomical decade variables equal 1 when the observation period has at least one year in that particular decade – with decades equal to 1940-1949, 1950-195, ... – and 0 otherwise, so that:

```
     start.year end.year 40s 50s 60s 70s 80s 90s 00s 10s
1       1957     1980     0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
2       1973     1998     0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
3       1943     1965     1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
4       1991     2011     0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1 
5       2001     2006     0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
6       1967     1984     0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
```

I saw the `cut` function but it looks to me – I might be wrong – that is not suited for this particular task when the variable to cut is actually a range made by two variables and not a single continuous variable.

What approach would you suggest? Is there a flexible way so that I could, in the future, adapt this to, let's say, dichotomical decade variables equal 1 when the observation period has at least 2/3/4(...)/9 year in that particular decade?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `floor` to decades and then with `Map` get the sequence from 'start.year' to 'end.year', and convert it to `table`

```
res <- cbind(db, as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(setNames(Map(function(x, y) 
        seq(x, y, by = 10), 
       (db$start.year %/% 10) * 10, (db$end.year %/% 10)*10), seq_len(nrow(db))))[2:1])))
names(res)[-(1:2)] <- substr(names(res)[-(1:2)], 3, 4) 
res
#  start.year end.year 40 50 60 70 80 90 00 10
#1       1957     1980  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
#2       1973     1998  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
#3       1943     1965  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
#4       1991     2011  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
#5       2001     2006  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
#6       1967     1984  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

---

If we are  using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
db %>% 
   mutate_all(funs((.%/%10)*10)) %>% 
   transmute(ind = row_number(), i1 = 1, 
             year = map2(start.year, end.year, ~seq(.x, .y, by = 10))) %>% 
   unnest %>%
   spread(year, i1, fill = 0) %>%
   select(-ind) %>%
   rename_all(substr, 3, 4) %>%
   bind_cols(db, .)
#  start.year end.year 40 50 60 70 80 90 00 10
#1       1957     1980  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
#2       1973     1998  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
#3       1943     1965  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
#4       1991     2011  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
#5       2001     2006  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
#6       1967     1984  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Personal preference, but this seems like exactly the type of situation where `%>%` makes things more reasable. `res <- Map(function(x, y) seq(x, y, by = 10), 
            (db$start.year %/% 10) * 10, 
            (db$end.year %/% 10) * 10) %>% 
        setNames(seq_len(nrow(db))) %>% 
        stack %>% 
        rev %>% 
        table %>% 
        as.data.frame.matrix %>% 
        {cbind(db, .)}`

Comment: @RobJensen If you are going by the `tidyverse`, then `map2` could be used

Comment: very nice solution. I didn't know about `map2`, that will simplify a lot of my code.